# I am getting Error because of Floating button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding, floating-action-button

In my code, I am using Databinding in XML file and I am getting an error because of a floating button in XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="userViewModel"
        type="com.example.projectdatabinding.viewModel.UserViewModel" />
</data>

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:visibility="@{userViewModel.progressBar}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/label_status"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@{userViewModel.messageLabel}"
                app:visibility="@{userViewModel.userLabel}" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/list_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:visibility="@{userViewModel.userRecycler}"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_user" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="@{userViewModel::onClickFabToLoad}"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the logcat I am getting Error like this :

```
Binary XML file line #59: Binary XML file line #59: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

and my gradle file is :

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.5'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

I saw many solutions like changes in gradle

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

and design gradle also

```
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

I have tried mostly all StackOverflow answers I could not get succeed, Thank you in advance

Comment: Check if `ic_account_circle_24dp` is present in all drawable folders and also verify that image is not corrupted

Comment: i have changed this already

Comment: Do you have seperate values folders in res ?

Comment: @Redman thank you I could not recognize that time finally I saw in my drawable folder it was like (24v)

Comment: Ok let me add an answer for future users .

Answer (score 0):

Check if `ic_account_circle_24dp` is present in all drawable folders and also verify that image is not corrupted .

Android self creates few folder like `drawable-v24` when adding  drawer. Make sure you delete that folder too .